# Using MONTHNAME and DATE_FORMAT together

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

I'm retrieving and storing a Date field from a database. On the graph I want to print only the "day of month" with month_name
DATE_FORMAT and MONTHNAME does the job, but not together. Any alternatives for the problem?

```
INPUT: 2015-02-20 00:00:10

OUTPUT: 20th Feb
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? When it comes to date/time, they are both far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Show your code and explain what is not working

Comment: I'm using MySQL. The code is `select MONTHNAME(startTime), duration from mytable`. This extracts only the name of month, but I also need the day of month as I have described in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I no longer see the Oracle reference mentioned by Marius, here's a MySQL option:

```
select date_format('2015-02-20 00:00:10','%D %b');
```

Returns:

```
20th Feb
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) are some other formatting options for the date_format function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(to_timestamp('2015-02-20 00:00:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'ddth Mon')
FROM dual
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL